# sigma-ring of sets generated by semiring, semiring closed under countable intersections

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $\mathcal H \subseteq \mathcal P(X)$ be a semiring, (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_sets#Related_structure).
Then the ring $\mathcal R$ generated by $\mathcal H$ (i.e. the smallest ring in $\mathcal P(X)$ containing $\mathcal H$), is given by 
$\mathcal R = \{\bigcup^n_{i=1} A_i: n \in \mathbb N, A_1,...,A_n \in \mathcal H \text{ disjoint}\}$.
I wonder why we cannot give an analog explicit description of the $\sigma$-ring(closed under countable unions, not only finite) generated by $\mathcal H$. My guess would be $\mathcal R = \{\bigcup^\infty_{i=1} A_i, A_i \in \mathcal H \text{ disjoint}\}$, i.e. allow countable infinite unions too. I tried to see where the proof in the case of rings doesnt go through to the case of $\sigma$-rings. For example, to show that the $\sigma$-ring generated by $\mathcal H$ is contained in $\mathcal R$, one shows that $\mathcal R$ is a $\sigma$-ring. Let $\{A_t\}_t$ be a countable collection of elements in $\mathcal R$. Then by the usual trick one could write $\bigcup_t A_t = \bigcup_t (A_t\setminus(\bigcup^{t-1}_{s=1} A_s)$ as disjoint union. So it is left to show that $\mathcal R$ is closed under finite unions and set differences. The problem lies here: to show closure under set differences one would need that $\mathcal H$ is closed under taking countable intersections. Which leads to the (probably not fruitful) question if it makes sense to define a class of semirings with this stronger property. Finally, even though the semi-ring of half-open intervals is not stable under countable intersections, for example the set of all closed intervals is, and this as well generates the Borel-sigma algebra of $\mathbb R$, but the closed intervals are not a semi-ring. The Borel-sigma algebra is generated by many different systems of sets. Does the above exclude the possibility that a generating system is a semi-ring that at the same time is stable under countable intersection? Finally, why is an 'explicit description' of the sigma-algebra in terms of 'countable set operations' impossible?

Comment: There are explicit descriptions of $\sigma$-algebra. They all use, in one way or another, transfinite constructions (for instance, transfinite induction).

Comment: Ah, yes. So my question still remains, is it true, that if the Borel sigma algebra is generated by a set $S$, this set cannot be both, a semiring and stable under countable intersections?

Comment: Let  $S$ be the semiring  of intervals in $\mathbb{R}$. Then $S$ is stable by countable intersection and the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb{R}$ is generated by $S$.

Comment: @Ramiro Why $ \ 1 \notin \bigcap_{n>0} [0,1+\frac{1}{n}] \ $? I think $ \ 0<1<1+\frac{1}{n}$, $\forall n>0$, don't you agree?

Comment: @Gustavo , Yes. you are right.

Comment: @Mekanik I am interested in this question too. I think we need to exhibit sets $X$ and $S$ such that $S$ is a semiring of sets for $X$, but $ \ \ \displaystyle \bar{S} = \left\{ \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty} E_j \in \wp(X) \ : \ (E_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}^*} \in S^{\mathbb{N}^*} \right\} \ $ is not a $\sigma$-ring of sets for $X$. I think your suspicion is correct, I think there exists sets $ \ E,F \in \bar{S} \ $ such that $ \ E \setminus F \notin \bar{S}$.

Comment: Note: In [a comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2806628/what-is-the-term-of-the-structure-set-of-countable-disjoint-unions-generated-b?noredirect=1#comment5787320_2806628) a paper is mentioned which shall answer this question