# What is the term of the structure: "set of countable disjoint unions generated by a semi-ring"?

Tags: measure-theory, terminology, definition, lebesgue-measure

Given a [semi-ring of sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Semi-ring_of_sets) $S$, the by $S$ generated [ring of sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_sets) $R$ is the set of all sets $A$ which are unions of pairwise disjoint sets $C_i\in S$ ($\bigsqcup$ shall be the [disjoint union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union)):

$$A\in R \iff \exists C_1,\ldots,C_n\in S: A = \bigsqcup_{i=1}^n C_i$$

If I extend this definition to countable unions, what type of set structure would I get? Let $T$ be a family of sets where all sets are countable unions of pairwise disjoint sets from the semi-ring:

$$A\in T \iff \exists C_i\in S: A = \bigsqcup_{i=1}^\infty C_i$$

> What is the term for the set structure $T$? Is $T$ the same as the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $S$? If not: How is such a structure called?

*My motivation:* The set of half-open intervals (rectangles, cuboids, ...) is a semi-ring. I want to know how to call the family of sets which are countable disjoint unions of half-open intervals (rectangles, cuboids, ...).

Comment: Not the same thing (I believe; I'm just doing a "hit and run" comment), but closely related is the notation of a [Dynkin class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system) (or Dynkin system, etc.). See [this paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-proceedings-of-the-cambridge-philosophical-society/article/div-classtitlethe-balls-do-not-generate-all-borel-sets-using-complements-and-countable-disjoint-unionsdiv/40BF5A85D67AE9B862B3B115B76EDD94) ([preprint version](http://web.cs.elte.hu/analysis/keleti/papers/hilbert.pdf)).

Answer (score 0):

The term you're looking for is $\sigma$-ring. The difference between a $\sigma$-ring and a $\sigma$-algebra is the requirement that $\sigma$-algebras be closed under complements.